# Scalapack wrapper for modern Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran2003, fortran2008

I am looking for a Fortran library that makes it easier to use Scalapack in my projects. It seems that using Scalapack without anything is very verbose and I was wondering if anyone has packed this into Fortran 2003 objects. I have seen similar things for C++ or Python. This attempt seems to have died a while ago:

https://github.com/dftbplus/scalapackfx

Are there any libraries that make it easier to use Scalapack?

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Note that library recommendations are off topic: *Questions asking us to **recommend or find** a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.*

Comment: So does the project you link contain the stuff you need or not? Or are you just worried it is not updated? Scalapack does not change that much.

Comment: All the links to the documentation are dead  and I can't find any examples. Without that it isn't much use.

Comment: That is a pretty normal thing. No-one likes to write documentation. The code is the documentation. There are some tests there, don't they serve as a kind of example?

Comment: But I don't think you can hope for much more if you searched and haven't find it already. I might be wrong, but I don't think there is anything like that for normal LAPACK either. There are Fortran95-style generic interfaces available, but not OOP.

Comment: With the 95(even 77)-Interface Lapack is already pretty easy, but Scalapack requires more work. Their sphinx documentation contains an example, but this isn't really helpful.

Comment: I guess OP has checked, and rejected, Intel's MKL, which provides Scalapack routines.

Comment: I am aware of Scalapack and Intels implementation of it. I was hoping to use it though a wrapper which makes it less verbose. All the examples I could find are very verbose, written in 77 and lack explanations: http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/examples/

Comment: I'm am aware that this is a vague question that doesn't really fit on Stackoverflow, but the general documentation on Scalapack is quite bad. I thought maybe someone else had found a way to improve on this.

Comment: Actually, the project did not die, on the contrary. We are using it heavily in DFTB+. However, we only add wrappers for functions we need. The documentation can be created via sphinx and the API-documentation via doxygen. And as has been point out below, there is even an online version available. (I'll try to move the documentation to Github and update the links...)

Comment: The links are dead even on the Bitbucket page.

Answer (score 0):

There is some documentation for scalapackfx at
https://aradi.bitbucket.io/scalapackfx/index.html
Is there a feature you need that is not present in the library?

Comment: This is the same software the OP is referencing. Notice that many links are dead. Both in the link the OP gave and in your link. Try to clock on the Online API documentation from here https://aradi.bitbucket.io/scalapackfx/routines.html But generally, asking just for external links is off topic here. This question should have been long closed.